# Yup array of objects get entire key value to check for "unique value error"

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

I have an array of objects where i am using formik and yup to validate the data as per the below schema

```
 validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
      fileData: Yup.array()
        .of(
          Yup.object().shape({
            Nome: Yup.string()
              .test("Nome", "Este campo é obrigatório", (value: any) => {
                if (value && value.length > 0) return true;
                else return false;
              })
              .required("Introduz uma data futura")
              .typeError("Introduz uma data futura"),
            "Data nascimento (DD-MM-AAAA)": Yup.string()
              .test(
                "Data nascimento (DD-MM-AAAA)",
                "Tem de ter entre",
                (value: any) => {
                  let date = moment(value, "DD-MM-YYYY");

                  return moment().diff(moment(date), "years") >= 18;
                }
              )
              .typeError("escolha uma data válida"),
            "Género (F ou M)": Yup.string()
              .test(
                "Género (F ou M)",
                "Este campo é obrigatório",
                (value: any) => {
                  if (
                    value &&
                    value.length > 0 &&
                    (value == "M" || value == "F")
                  )
                    return true;
                  else return false;
                }
              )
              .required("Introduz uma data futura")
              .typeError("Introduz uma data futura"),
            Email: Yup.string()
              .test("Email", "Este campo é obrigatório", (value: any) => {
       
                if (value) return true;
                else {
                  return true;
                }
              })
              .typeError("Introduz uma data futura"),
          })
        )
        .nullable(),
    }),
```

as you can see I have an email field as of now if the email is empty i get error as you can check the screenshot below [image: error message]

Now I want to add a test function so that i can validate for the unique email, such as if we have 2 same emails i get the error in the same way as we have in the ss, so is there a way i could get all values inside test function to check for the uniqueness ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.parent` in test function

Yup.addMethod will go before components

```
Yup.addMethod(Yup.array, 'unique', function (message, path) {
  return this.test('unique', message, function (list) {
    const mapper = x => x[path];
    const set = [...new Set(list.map(mapper))];
    const isUnique = list.length === set.length;
    if (isUnique) {
      return true;
    }

    const idx = list.findIndex((l, i) => mapper(l) !== set[i]);
    return this.createError({ path: `${this.path}[${idx}].${path}`, message });
  });
});
```

and

```
 validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
      fileData: Yup.array()
        .of(
            ...
            ...
            ...
        )
      .unique(
        "Already part of the emails",
        'Email',
      ),
        .nullable(),
    }),
```

Comment: fileData or say this.parent gives me the current object, not the array of objects :(

Comment: @Naruto updated try this